# Product attribute values resetting at midnight everyday

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, cron, magento-cron

I've posted something similar before and no one replied with a decent answer, so I'm posting a new thread so it will have some fresh eyes.

I'm having huge problems with Magento 2, every night at midnight, the product attribute values will reset to default.

For example, if I set a product to be the colour 'RED', at midnight it will change to the 'Default' value.

I've been in touch with our developer and our hosting provider, and they are still unable to find the error.

Our developer said that it's due to a plugin that manages our stock levels (BrightPearl), however, the connection works on a SKU basis and does NOT touch product variants.

Our hosting provider has setup a ticket and will be monitoring the changes to the cron_schedule from 11:30pm to 12:30pm to see the changes and to see what is changing. However, they've done this before and they found nothing.

We've been told previously to ensure that we edit our products on 'All store views' to ensure that nothing will be affected, which is still has.

I hope someone has had a similar experience or problem with Magento 2 and has a fix. If you do, please share with me as we are a constantly growing retail business on Magento 1 who plan to launch our Magento 2 website with a fresh design as soon as possible.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Why not you are trying by disabling the BrightPearl plugin which is recommended by your developer?

Comment: We have done so, but we need that plugin.

Comment: Yes I understand. From this at least you will get idea that the problem is with the extension or somewhere else.

Comment: We've already tested this, it doesn't seem to be the problem - any other ideas?

Comment: Ok then install any cron scheduler module through which you will get an idea that which cron update the product attribute values.

Comment: I think I've found the issue, we created 2 new product attributes that do the exact same thing, but they are different types, we are now using standard 'dropdowns' and they have not reset since Saturday. However, the products with the current values for size and color, are a visual swatch and text swatch - so this looks like it could be a problem, either with the attribute set OR the type we are setting the attribute too.

Comment: Thats great!...

Comment: Okay, so it's definitely not that. Tested that, and it still rolled back. We are now lead to believe that it could be setting the swatch to 'required' apparently this could conflict with some extensions? What do you think, from experience?